# Put the $i$th term to be the coefficient of $x^i$: A question about Mathematical notation and sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Take $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ to be integer polynomials, and then interpret them as sequences in the obvious way: i.e. you put the $i$th term to be the coefficient of $x^i$.

$u(x)=x-2$, $v(x)=3x^2+x$. The sequences are:
$$
\dots u_{-2}=u_{-1}=0;\  \ u_0=-2;\  \ u_1=1; \  \ u_2=u_3=\dots=0
$$
$$
\dots v_{-2}=v_{-1}=v_0=0;\  \ v_1=1;\  \ v_2=3;\  \ v_3=v_4=\dots=0
$$

Why is $u_{-2}=u_{-1}=0$?

Comment: Could you explain that algebraically?

Comment: The first sentence of the post says exactly that the i-th term is the coefficient of $x^i$. So what's the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ in $x-2$? Looks like it's $0$.

Comment: @coffeemath: I didn't fully understand why u1 = 1 and not u1 = u(1)=1-2=-1 and why v1=1 and not v1 = v(1)=3*1^2+1=4, etc, etc...

Comment: The $1$ in $u_1$ is just a subscript. Like in the definition of slope $m=(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$. So $u_1$ does not mean $u(1)$, instead $u(1)$ means plug in $1$ for $x$ in the definition of $u(x)$.

Comment: I guess I simply don't understand the english term 'coefficient'. What does it mean in this context.

Comment: Suggestion: when you get answers to questions, you can "accept" one answer per question. You can do this by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You can also upvote as many answers as you care to. These are good things to do, since it helps users know if they've helped, makes them more likely to help in the future, plus, when you accept an answer, you get 2 reputation points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the construction of polynomials (over $\mathbb Z$, for example) starts with the set of sequences with elements in $\mathbb Z$. Now you have to know what is such a sequence: it is simply a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$. How can we write such a function by using its values? For example in this way: $(f(n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$. Now which sequence corresponds to the polynomial $X$? Well, this is the sequence $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ defined by $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and $f(n)=0$ for all $n>1$, or, if you like it, the sequence $(0,1,0,0, \dots)$. To $3X^2+X$ corresponds $(0,1,3,0,0\dots)$. To conclude: there are no negative indices involved in the construction of the ring of polynomials!